# Why "underfull box" message is printed?

Tags: spacing, tex-core

In TeXbook, p.27, it is said:

[image]

And further:

> If there’s no way to meet these restrictions, you get an overfull box.

Here is how to [reproduce](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex) this text:

```
\input manmac
\begindisplay
\hbox spread-1em{You don't get spaces between words narrower than this,\ and}\cr
\hbox spread+1.679895em{you don't get spaces between words wider than this.}\cr
\enddisplay
\end
```

The questions are:

1) where the `spread` values come from

2) why if we use, say, `spread+1.7em` no warning is printed

3) warning starts to appear only when we say `spread+2.9em` - why the warning is `Underfull \hbox ...` - not "overfull box" (as the book says)?

Comment: To be more exact (like in the second spread), the first spread should be `-1.010002em`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in Knuth is about breaking paragraphs into lines. `TeX` can make spaces narrower or wider while doing that, but it never produces underfull boxes by itself, only overfull boxes. To make an underfull box, you'll have to do something manually, like insert manual `\break` (or use a `\hbox` with some bigger spread).

As for the values of `spread`, I guess they are found by trial and error to reach the maximum value of badness which is still acceptable by Plain TeX (the value of 200).

---

You may use this snippet to see the ratio `r` for each `\hbox`:

```
\tracingonline=1
\showboxdepth=0
\input manmac
\begindisplay
\setbox0=\hbox spread-1em{You don't get spaces between words narrower than this,\ and}%
\showbox0
\box0 \cr
\setbox0=\hbox spread+1.679895em{you don't get spaces between words wider than this.}%
\showbox0
\box0 \cr
\enddisplay
\end
```

Comment: Indeed, `spread+1.679895em` gives ratio `r` equal to 1.25993. Badness corresponding to this ratio is 200 (100*r^3).

Comment: As for `spread-1em`, it is the smallest shrink that gives ratio of 1 (ratios greater than 1 are not permitted for shrink).

Comment: The value of spread after which underfull box message appears is `spread+2.87764em` (found by trial and error). Ratio corresponding to this spread is 2.15825, and badness is thus 1000. And this is what `\hbadness` is equal to in plain TeX.

Comment: Do you mean that the "overfull box" message will appear when badness>200 when this line is in a real paragraph, not in an hbox? Can you give any example?

Comment: No, TeX won't create a paragraph with lines that have badness higher than 200. But it starts reporting underfull hboxes from a higher threshold value. By default it's 1000 (page 29).

Comment: Overfull box happens when it's impossible to break a paragraph in a way that all lines have badness lower than 200. Tex gives up and stick some word to the right margin. Just set a very narrow `\textwidth` and you'll see an overfull hbox.

Comment: Now I understand: I just misinterpreted the words "you get an overfull box" - they concern not the specific box which has wrong size, but in general, in the paragraph, on previous line, as you pointed out in your comment.

Comment: Actually, "underfull box" can be produced when a paragraph is full of long words that are not able to be hyphenated.  Inclusion of a url in a bibliography entry is one such notable situation.